Is this central limit theorem?
Context: I have an implementation of Wilson's algorithm for generating uniform spanning trees. After generating 1 million instances of USTs on a K5 (complete graph with 5 edges), I plot a histogram of the frequency of individual trees:

This makes sense because we have 125 possible spanning trees on a K5, and we see a (relatively) uniform distribution among each. The data that I give to my software to create this plot is a list of length 1 million, containing values {1, 2, ..., 125}. For example, [1, 4, 46, 30, 77, 110, ... ]
But I've noticed that if I "pre-aggregate" the frequencies, meaning for each of the 125 spanning trees, I find the number of times it was generated, and plot a histogram of this, I get a normal distribution:

The data being plotted here is a list of length 125, containing the counts of each tree. For example [7900, 8000, 8100 ... ].
My question is: Is this central limit theorem? The context I've been taught about CLT has been about the distribution of means approaching normal, so I'm confused here because I am not (to my knowledge) taking any averages.

You shouldn't fuss over the distinction between a sum, count, or (arithmetic) mean: each of your frequencies, divided by the total length of the simulation, is an average of the indicator of its tree (equal to 1 when the tree is the solution and 0 otherwise).  That gives you a set of 125 nearly independent realizations of a Binomial$(10^6, 1/125)$ random variable. You can view that as a manifestation of the CLT if you like, but it's not necessary.  Indeed, your simulation was unnecessary: it shows only that your implementation does not depend on the order in which vertices are listed.

@whuber thanks for your reply! I'm a bit lost in your explanation and would appreciate some clarification:
"each of your frequencies, divided by the total length of the simulation, is an average of the indicator of its tree (equal to 1 when the tree is the solution and 0 otherwise)"
A bit unsure about how this gives me independent realizations of Binomial(10^6, 1/125).

This is a Multinomial distribution.  Each component is Binomial.  They are not quite independent, because they sum to $10^6.$
